# Python: Create a Dict of Tuple (int, Counter) types

Tags: python

I want to have a dict(tuple(int, Counter)).

```
    variable = defaultdict(int,Counter)
    TypeError: descriptor 'keys' of 'dict' object needs an argument
```

I have IP addresses that can be associated with multiple values, such as a ttl value and MAC addresses, so I want to count which ttl value appears the most, and I want to associate it (via the int) with the other ttl values.

How do I declare this type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a lambda as the defaultdict initializer

```
 variable = defaultdict(lambda : (int(), Counter()))
```

Comment: Follow up comment for all the marbles.  How then do I index into this? variable[string][int,string]?

Comment: You could use `i, counter = variable[key]` with the key of your choice.

Comment: but how do i insert a string value? (this should have been the original question).

Comment: ``variable[key][1].update({'mystring':2})``or ``variable[key][1]['fish'] += 1`` depending on your usage.